# Add image to Flask table by referencing item in row

Tags: python, html, for-loop, flask, dynamic-programming

While looping over a tuple of tuples I am trying to reference an image in my static folder with the same name as the first item of the inner tuple.

Here is how I am trying to accomplish this, my code is below:

**app.py**

```
@app.route("/output)
  heading = ("smiles", "calculation_output")
  data = (
  ("smilesA", float)
  ("smilesB", float)
  ("smilesC", float)
  )
  return render_template(output.html, heading=heading, data=data)
```

**output.html**

```
<table border="1">
        <tr>
                {% for header in headings %}
                <th>{{ header }}</th>
                {% endfor %}<th>Image</th>
        </tr>
        {% for row in data %}
        <tr>
                {% for cell in row %}
                <td>{{ cell }}</td>                                                                                                                                 
                {% endfor %}
                <td><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/' + {{cell[0]}})}}"></td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
</table>
```

What I really need is a way to reference the first item in the inner tuple, but I cannot find the correct way to do so.

**Solution**

I had to remove the double curly brackets and add a " + '.png'"

```
<table border="1">
        <tr>
                {% for header in headings %}
                <th>{{ header }}</th>
                {% endfor %}<th>Image</th>
        </tr>
        {% for row in data %}
        <tr>
                {% for cell in row %}
                <td>{{ cell }}</td>                                                                                                                                 
                {% endfor %}
                <td><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/' + row[0] + '.png')}}"></td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: try `<img src=" url_for('static', filename='images/{{cell[0]}}')`

Comment: maybe convert values to `'images/' + cell[0] + '.png'` before sending to template

Comment: you have two `for`-loop `for row in data: for cell in row` - so it seems you don't need `cell[0]`  but `cell` or `row[0]`. But I think you should remove `for cell in row` and use `row[0]` and `row[1]` to create row with different objects. In current code `cell[0]` should get first char from word `"smilesA"` -> `"s"`

Comment: @furas you are correct I updated my solution to show this